# Is half stepping possible by powering the two consecutive coils?

Tags: stepper-motor

I have some stepper motors with a step angle of 1.8 degrees and I am wondering if it is possible that powering the coils next to each would it get the spindle to go to midpoint between the two coils? So for example power coil 3 and 4 to get it to go between both points(so step angle between 0.9 degrees) or will it keep moving very slightly? I only ask as the stepper motors are at college and its the weekend so can't test it.

Comment: i think that's actually the definition of half-stepping. at least, that's what it was back in the days of moving the head in a floppy drive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally yes, although the half step positions may be slightly less accurate than the full ones. Bear in mind you are putting twice the power through the motor so heat may be more of an issue.

Comment: If you can control the ratio of current to the two coils, you can get other "in-between" positions.  This is called "microstepping."  Accuracy varies.